# Meaning of ぞや at the end of 「 日本語は何ぞや」？

Tags: translation

What is the meaning of ぞや at the end of

> 日本語は何ぞや?

Comment: What is the context? Is it from https://www.imabi.net/intro-to-japanese ?

Comment: @YusukeMatsubara Is this construction quite rare in the modern language? I have never seen it before.

Comment: Rare in the form 日本語は何ぞや, but not so much in the form 日本語とは何ぞや. Wonder if the lack of と was intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [a combined particle](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%9E%E3%82%84/) ぞ(emphasis) + や(question).

In terms of modern usage, Xとは何{なん}ぞや is a way to emphasize a question, probably more often used in writing than in speech. It is usually used in contexts like "let's redefine/ask ourselves *what is X*" or "wait, but *what exactly is X in the first place*".

Another (still current) usage of ぞや is to add indefiniteness ([ぞ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%9E/#jn-127855) [副助]#1).

- そこはいつぞやいったことがある I've been there sometime-I-don't-remember.
- どこぞやで食べた気がする I've tasted it somewhere-I-don't-know.

いつか/どこか can replace いつぞや/どこぞや above.